# Is there anything similar in C#/Java to do the following?

Tags: c#, java

In Javascript(JQuery), we can use map method to convert an array to another using a callback method. This is a great advantage of FP.

I am wondering if we can do the same thing in C# or Java?

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use a [projection with LINQ](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-09787825):

```
myCollection.Select(element => new MyOtherType { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, Array has the [ConvertAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx) method that literally does what you are asking for.

However, it takes a delegate as the argument, so for a concise way of writing it you'll want to use a lambda expression, making it quite similar to the projection as suggested by devdigital.